# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: './img/'

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Hi I'm having an issue with being able to use a image file in my embeds thumbnail. 
I keep getting the error:

`PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: './img/'`

The file is in this folder.

Here is the code that I'm working with:

```
@commands.command(invoke_without_command=True, case_insensitive=True)
@checks.is_channel_mod()
async def changelog(self, ctx):

    with open("changelog.txt") as f:
        changelog = f.read()

        embed = discord.Embed(description=changelog,  title='**__CHANGELOG__**', colour=discord.Color(random.randint(0x000000, 0xFFFFFF)))
        embed.add_field(name="__**Have a Suggestion?**__", value="Please tell us about it in <#555371532390760473>", inline=False)
        embed.set_thumbnail(url="attachment://changelog.png")
        return {
            "file": discord.File("./img/")
        }

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Windows or Linux?  What are the permissions on the file and its directory?  `./img/` is a directory, so even if you had permission, you would get a `IsADirectoryError`.

Comment: Testing on Windows but Hosted on Linux

Comment: Which are you getting the error in?  Have you tried opening up the permission on `./img/`?

Comment: Im getting the error in windows.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have figured it out, here is my answer:

```
@commands.command(invoke_without_command=True, case_insensitive=True)
@checks.is_channel_mod()
async def changelog(self, ctx):

    with open("changelog.txt") as f:
        changelog = f.read()
        f = discord.File(f"./img/changelog.png", f"changelog.png") 
        embed = discord.Embed(description=changelog,  title='**__CHANGELOG__**', colour=discord.Color(random.randint(0x000000, 0xFFFFFF)))
        embed.add_field(name="__**Have a Suggestion?**__", value="Please tell us about it in <#555371532390760473>", inline=False)
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=f"attachment://changelog.png")

    await ctx.send(file=f, embed=embed)
```